# How to create a simple UDP packet to transmit to Radio (OMNETPP)?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to understand to create a packet using PACKET API in inet 4.0. This is a new API in inet 4.0.

```
 std::ostringstream str;

 Packet *packet = new Packet(str.str().c_str());

 const auto& payload = makeShared<ApplicationPacket>();

 payload->setChunkLength(B(par("packetLength")));

 payload->setSequenceNumber(0);

 auto macAddressReq = packet->addTag<MacAddressReq>(); // add new tag for MAC

 macAddressReq->setSrcAddress(SrcAddress); // source is our MAC address

 macAddressReq->setDestAddress(DestAddress); // destination is next hop

 auto interfaceReq = packet->addTag<InterfaceReq>(); // add tag for dispatch

 interfaceReq->setInterfaceId(1); // set designated interface

 auto packetProtocolTag = packet->addTagIfAbsent<PacketProtocolTag>();

 packetProtocolTag->setProtocol(&Protocol::ipv4); // set protocol of packet

 encapsulate(packet);

 send(packet, "radioOut");
```

There is no error in compilation but there is an error during simulation.

Simulation ERR MSG:

[image: Error]

I am sure the error is due to packet creation. I am trying to understand based on developers-guides. But It doesn't have much information to solve the problem.

https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/developers-guide/index.html